# How do I create a pie chart that displays the proportion of users who have completed a specific course?

Tags: tableau-desktop

So I have a workbook and in this workbook I have a bunch of user id's. These users are doing different courses. I want to calculate the fraction of users that have already finished a specific course divided by the count of user ids.

So let's say that course abc is mandatory and I want to see how many of them have finished the course abc. My idea was to do something like:

```
count(if [course] = 'abc' then [userid] end).
```

Then I would like to divide this by the count of user id's.

So something like:

```
 

count(if [course] = 'abc' then [userid] end) / countd([user id]).
```

But this doesn't show me the fraction in the pie chart, I want to see that for example out of 20 people (10 unique people), 7 people have already finished the course 'abc'.

How do I visualize it in a pie chart?

Basically I have one measure which is the user id and a dimension and in that dimension I have many courses. But I just want to look at this one specific course.

I created calculated fields that count the number of users that finished course 'abc'
Then I divided it by the count of user id's. But I only get the number of people who finished the course. For example 7 out of 20 people finished course 'abc' but in the pie chart I just see 7. No fraction.

I was thinking to nest it into a if... else statement but I'm not sure how.
So thatin in the if statement it says 'course finished' and the else statement shows 'not finished/in progress'.